# Proof $\sum{ k{ x }^{ -k }=\frac { x }{ { (x-1) }^{ 2 } } }$

Tags: derivatives, proof-verification, power-series

As the title says, I want to prove the following:

$$\sum {k{x}^{-k}=\frac{x}{{(x-1)}^{2}}}$$

But I think I am doing something wrong. I start from the following:

$$\sum{x^k} = \frac{x}{1-x} \implies \sum{kx^k}=\frac{d}{dx} \frac{x}{1-x}$$

So I take that

$$\sum{kx^{-k}}=\frac{d}{dx} \frac{x^{-1}}{1-x^{-1}}$$

I work this out:

$$
\frac { d }{ dx } \frac { x^{ -1 } }{ 1-x^{ -1 } } =\frac { \frac { -1 }{ x^{ 2 } } \left( 1-\frac { 1 }{ x }  \right) -\frac { 1 }{ x } \frac { 1 }{ x^{ 2 } }  }{ { \left( 1-\frac { 1 }{ x }  \right)  }^{ 2 } } \\ =\frac { \frac { -1 }{ x^{ 2 } } +\frac { 1 }{ x^{ 3 } } -\frac { 1 }{ x^{ 3 } }  }{ { \left( 1-\frac { 1 }{ x }  \right)  }^{ 2 } } \\ =\frac { \frac { -1 }{ x^{ 2 } }  }{ 1-\frac { 2 }{ x } +\frac { 1 }{ x^{ 2 } }  } \\ =\quad \frac { { -x }^{ 2 } }{ 1-2{ x }^{ -1 }+{ x }^{ -2 } } \\ =\quad \frac { -{ x }^{ 2 } }{ { x }^{ -2 }\left( \frac { 1 }{ { x }^{ -2 } } -\frac { 2{ x }^{ -1 } }{ { x }^{ -2 } } +1 \right)  } \\ =\quad \frac { -1 }{ \left( { x }^{ 2 }-2x+1 \right)  } \\ =\quad \frac { -1 }{ { \left( x-1 \right)  }^{ 2 } } 
$$
Which is not the desired result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $\sum x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}$

Comment: Also, $\frac{d}{dx} x^k=kx^{k-1}$, not $kx^k$

Comment: Also, this statement is wrong: http://cl.ly/image/2B141z1Q0D2y

Comment: @ASKASK it could be the summation starts at $k=1$.

Comment: Oh I see. Still, I have pointed out two other errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question isn't clear, I'll assume the sum is from $k = 0$ to $\infty$

$$\sum_{k\ge 0} kx^{-k} = -x \sum_{k\ge 0} (-k)x^{-k-1} = -x\;\frac{d}{dx}\! \left(\sum_{k\ge 0} x^{-k}\right) = -x \;\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x^{-1}} \right)$$

You do the rest